# Wired doorbell problem

Tags: doorbell

Doorbell does not ring. Tested wires to buttons, they have power.
The chime unit seems to have power to both back and front all the time, even after disconnecting wires from both buttons. Not sure worth tracking it down, could it be something else besides a short in doorbell wiring?

Comment: For both doorbells? Unlikely.  More likely a broken wire in the part of the circuit common to both buttons.  Something may be off with your testing method.   Phantom (induced) voltages perhaps i.e. Crosstalk from power wires? I know 24v loads are hard to find, but it would help to test under a load of some kind.

Comment: It's also possible that a stuck button fried the chime coil.  If that's the case you'll need a new chime.  Replace the buttons too.